# Ethics and legality of scraping (and ultimately publishing about) publicly available information from journal websites

Tags: ethics, data, legal-issues

I'm interested in scraping publicly available information from journal websites (such as article titles, authors, abstracts, and keywords).

After scraping the data, I'm interested in analyzing the data and possibly publishing the findings.

Apart from open access journals for which this is likely less of (or not) an issue, what are the ethics and legality of scraping publicly available information from journal websites?

Comment: I don't see any ethical issue whatsoever.  In terms of legal issues: you could look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_scraping#Legal_issues.  The laws are just emerging here but very roughly, if you are not damaging the scrapee (either through implementing extracted information in a way that is detrimental to their business or significantly slowing down the running of their site), it seems to be okay.  In the case at hand, it sounds like you want information other third parties already collect and post.  This makes me think it would not be a problem (but I certainly don't know).

Comment: In general, the legality will be covered by the terms of use on the websites from which you are scraping. If they forbid scraping, I suppose you *might* be legally required not to. I say might, because as a non-lawyer I don't know whether such terms are legally permissible and therefore binding.

Comment: Hi Josua. I'm interested in doing this kind of analysis too. Would be great to share my ideas with you, so we can mine papers for different purposes, but using similar tools, including the ones you are developing. Let me know, we can have a private conversation about that.

Comment: That would be good. I'm at jrosen@msu.edu, send me a note!

Comment: @PeteL.Clark Can you please turn your comment into an answer so that I can vote for it?